# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to run a mysql query to find all occurences of a text. I have a syntax error but dont know where or how to fix it

I am using sqlyog to execute this script

```
DECLARE @url VARCHAR(255)

SET @url = '1720'

SELECT 'select * from ' + RTRIM(tbl.name) + ' where ' + 
          RTRIM(col.name) + ' like %' + RTRIM(@url) + '%'
FROM sysobjects tbl
INNER JOIN syscolumns col ON tbl.id = col.id 
AND col.xtype IN (167, 175, 231, 239) -- (n)char and (n)varchar, there may be others to include
AND col.length > 30 -- arbitrary min length into which you might store a URL
WHERE tbl.type = 'U'    -- user defined table
```

1 queries executed, 0 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings

Query: declare @url varchar(255) set @url = '1720' select 'select * from ' + rtrim(tbl.name) + ' where ' + rtrim(col.name) + ' like %' ...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare @url varchar(255)

Comment: The easy way to do this is to remove one statement at a time, until the error disappears - it helps narrow things down.

Comment: @LuisEValencia: It looks like you are porting a SQL Server script to MySQL.  I thought this was mistagged, but the error message returned is clearly from MySQL.  The syntax in the script is clearly SQL Server. See my answer for a somewhat equivalent MySQL query.

Comment: The title of this question really should  be changed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For MySQL change this:

```
DECLARE @url VARCHAR(255)
SET @url = '1720'
```

to:

```
SET @url := '1720'
```

In MySQL, you don't DECLARE user variables, just set them to a value. The equal sign works for assignment, except within a SQL statement, where you need to use the Pascal-style `:=` as the assignment operator. (I typically use the `:=` assignment operator in the context of the SET statement, even though in the equal sign works equally fine.)

However, in looking at your SQL statement, it appears this is Microsoft SQL Server syntax, what with the `+` operator for concatenation, the references to sysobjects, syscolumns.xtype.

There is no way this statement is going to returning anything useful from MySQL.

That whole statement needs to be re-written to query:

```
information_schema.tables
information_schema.columns
```

As an example starting point:

```
SET @url := 'foobar';

SELECT CONCAT('select * from `',col.table_schema
             ,'`.`',col.table_name
             ,'` where `',col.column_name
             ,'` like ''%',RTRIM(@url),'%''') AS q
  FROM information_schema.columns col 
  JOIN information_schema.tables tbl
    ON tbl.table_schema = col.table_schema
   AND tbl.table_name = col.table_name
   AND tbl.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
 WHERE col.data_type IN ('varchar','char')
   AND col.character_maximum_length >= 30
   AND col.table_schema = 'mydatabase';
```

---

**UPDATE:**

To include an 'query id' in the resultset of each query, so you can identify which of those queries is returning a row...

```
SELECT CONCAT('select ',@rn := @rn + 1, ' as q, t.* from `',col.table_schema
             ,'`.`',col.table_name
             ,'` t where `',col.column_name
             ,'` like ''%',RTRIM(@url),'%''') AS q
  FROM (SELECT @rn := 0) r
  JOIN information_schema.columns col 
  JOIN information_schema.tables tbl
    ON tbl.table_schema = col.table_schema
   AND tbl.table_name = col.table_name
   AND tbl.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
 WHERE col.data_type IN ('varchar','char')
   AND col.character_maximum_length >= 30
   AND col.table_schema = 'mydatabase';
```

Comment: I get this: Unknown column 'tbl.name' in 'field list'

Comment: @LuisEValencia: I edited it, the SQL statement should return a result set from MySQL now.

Comment: these are the generated sql: SELECT * FROM `theprint_depotlive-v16`.`zizio_groupsale` WHERE `zizio_object_id` LIKE '%1720%'
 but it says I have a syntax error

Comment: lol nevermind, its missing the ; at the end of each query

Comment: @LuisEValencia: the generated SELECT statements look fine to me. If you are going to execute more than one SELECT statement, they need to be separated by semicolons, otherwise MySQL can't tell where one statement ends and the next one begins... and get ready to duck when the DBA finds you...

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget semicolons:

```
DECLARE @url VARCHAR(255);
SET @url = '1720';
SELECT  .... ;
```

Also, `@` has special meaning in Mysql (looks like you porting T-SQL script). You don't need to declare it in contrast to local variable (without `@` that are used in the body of SP/Function/Trigger)

Comment: ok fine, but the script wont search anything.  Table 'theprint_depotlive-v17.sysobjects' doesn't exist

Comment: You are trying to run SQLServer script on Mysql . These 2 RDMS have quite different structure of system tables/views and even sql dialect. Unless you made a mistake in tagging your question, you need to completely rewrite the query.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can't use "Declare" without scope, you can only use it in Begin...End block (like: in stored procedures, etc).
You don't need the "Declare..." line, just setting the variable @url is enough for the script to run.