# SQL query works in mySQL but not in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I have the following query ( its actually more complex but just used a basic one for this purpose)

```
 "DECLARE @x1 FLOAT; SET @x1 = 8; Select @x1"
```

which works fine directly with mySQL database but when I use it in java Like this:

```
String sqlFormula = "DECLARE @x1 FLOAT; SET @x1 = 8; Select @x1";
```

I send this query in the same way I do others which work fine but this is giving me SQL syntax error. Does java require variable declaration in a different format??

The error is:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @x1
>   FLOAT; SET @x1 = 8; Select @x1' at line 1

Which doesn't really help as it refers to the whole line.

Adding Begin and End to the string:

```
String sqlFormula = "BEGIN DECLARE @x1 FLOAT; SET @x1 = 8; Select @x1 END";
```

In doing this the Begin bit is fine but it seems to add END to the statement. The error reports syntax error:

> 'DECLARE @x1 FLOAT; SET @x1 = 8; Select @x1 END' at line 1

Thanks.

Comment: *"in the same way I do others"* And how is that? --- *"giving me SQL syntax error"* Show us the error.

Comment: Please be careful when tagging. mysql <> sql server.

Comment: @Andreas I edited above to show the error.

Comment: According to [MySQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html): *`DECLARE` is permitted only inside a `BEGIN ... END` compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.*

Comment: @Andreas It seems to add End to the statement but not Begin. See edited above.

Comment: So according to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222677/you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-check-the-manual-that-corresponds-to-your)  Declare is not required. So I omitted that part and I can now set the variable but its now having issues with SELECT

Comment: Please read the manual: [`[begin_label:] BEGIN [statement_list] END [end_label]`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/begin-end.html): *statement_list represents a list of one or more statements, **each terminated by a semicolon (;)** statement delimiter.* Your `SELECT` is missing the `;`.

Comment: I did add it and was the following "BEGIN SET @x1 =7; SELECT @x1; END", so must of been a typo. I also have set the permissions. It was complaining about the syntax as I mentioned above. It clearly doesn't like multiple statements in one string. Hence, why I sent them individually.

Answer (score -1):

As it turns out there was nothing wrong with the syntax it was the multiple statements in one query that it didn't like. I implemented them individually and it worked. Its not ideal but will do for now until I create a prepared statement later.

Comment: See connection property [`allowMultiQueries`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html): *Allow the use of ';' to delimit multiple queries during one statement (true/false), defaults to 'false'.*

Comment: Yep. already did that. Appended "?allowMultiQueries=TRUE" to database when connecting. No difference in result.